# Right permissions FTP server

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I need create a FTP server to upload files directly to apache directory. I have create user with: 
`useradd -G wheel,apache newuser` 
and set password with 
`passwd newuser`

I have changed home directory of newuser in `/etc/passwd` file from `/home/newuser` to `/var/www/html_newuser` and set permission to folder:
 `/var/www/html_newuser` with:

`chown -R apache.apache /var/www/html_newuser` and `chmod -R 755 /var/www/html_newuser`

When i try to upload file into FTP directory i have

```
553 Could not create file.
```

P.S. The same configuration work perfectly in Centos 6.5, this is a Centos 7

Answer (score 1):

s/755/2775/

You're setting the owner to `apache`, denying group write permissions, and using `newuser` to attempt to upload. Given your scheme, you want to allow group write permissions, and I recommend 2775 versus 775 in order to keep new files owned by the `apache` group at creation.

Comment: with 2775, when connect with FTP client i have this error: `500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()`

Comment: Then you need to either make the directory owned by the `newuser` user, or you need to modify the VSFTPd configuration. Either way, this is not the same configuration as you have on your CentOS 6.5 server, or you would be getting identical errors.

Comment: I resolved inserted `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` to vsftpd.conf...seems to work